# Android App that simulates input events

Tags: android

We are looking into creating an android app that can simulate input events on our company devices. When we need to update or configure a device we would push the app on our employees devices and have it perform some set of inputs to configure it correctly.

It looks like its possible, there are apps like AutoInput and RepetiTouch which can be set up to simulate input on a device.

Whats the best way to accomplish this in Android?

Comment: I don't know if this can work without root access.. Not sure though